# CouchDB - rewrite urls for views issue

Tags: url-rewriting, couchdb, url-routing

I'm trying to rewrite urls for my views (application will use CouchDB virtual host):

```
"from": "/views/*",
"to": "_view/*",
"method": "*",
"query": {}
```

So, when I try to access:

```
db/_design/db/_rewrite/views/
```

in log there is such info:

```
rewrite to "/db/_design/db/_view"
```

As expected, I get `{"error":"method_not_allowed","reason":"Only GET,POST,HEAD allowed"}`

But if I try to reach some view function:

```
db/_design/db/_rewrite/views/all
```

in log I get a very strange (for me) message:

```
rewrite to "/db/views/all?doc=views&attachment=all"
```

And then I get 404 response. I can access view via standard URL: `db/_design/db/_view/all` and everything works fine. And my other rewrite rules works fine too. I can reach my view with the following rewrite rule:

```
"from": "/allview",
"to": "_view/all"
```

Where I'm doing it wrong?

CouchDB 1.0.1, CouchApp 0.7.6, Ubuntu Linux 10.10

Comment: It seems, that this issue related to CouchApp - on a fresh CouchDB database this issue not reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you have any other rewrite rules which might be interfering with this one? That might explain why in a fresh database it isn't an issue.